# Xaero's minimap mod waypoint going across multiple worlds MINECRAFT

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make waypoints not show up through multiple worlds (if I make a waypoint at 1,48,19 in one world then go to another, it will be in that world to). I have tried figuring this out many times by looking through the settings of the mod, searching forums, googling it, searching youtube, ect. Your help is greatly appreciated and thanks for your time.

P.S. I also use Xaeros minimap mod, and this is for Minecraft.

Comment: So in your research, what did you find?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate waypoint group for each world then change to the appropriate group when you travel to and from your various worlds.

Comment: Matt, how do i do that and sorry i didnt answer sooner

Comment: @xXSPENCERXx - Bring up the waypoint list (hotkey is set in the normal way inside Minecraft), click on the top list (I think it says 'Default') and add a new list.  Then you can create waypoints in the new list.  To change click on the list name at the top and choose from your 'list of lists'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set them manually.

Xaeros minimap saves the coordinates, but not specific for each world.